# Initialize std::unique_ptr as a raw array pointer is initialized

Tags: c++, arrays, initialization, std, unique-ptr

I currently have a small OpenGL project wherein I create an array on the heap with,

```
float* vertices = new float[48] {
     0.5f,  0.5f, 0.5f,  1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,  // front top right,    0
     0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f,  0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,  // front bottom right, 1
    -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f,  0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,  // front bottom left,  2
    -0.5f,  0.5f, 0.5f,  0.4f, 0.8f, 0.2f,  // front top left,     3

     0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,  // back top right,     4
     0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,  // back bottom right,  5
    -0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,  // back bottom left,   6
    -0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f, 0.4f, 0.8f, 0.2f   // back top left,      7 
};
```

I am anticipating expanding this to many hundreds or a thousand values.  Thus, I would like to use a `std::unique_ptr`.  I have looked at the documentation and it does not seem that initializing a `std::unique_ptr` like a raw array pointer is possible.  Nonetheless, I have tried writing something like this,

```
std::unique_ptr<float[]> vertices(new float[48])  {
    0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,     // front top right,    0
    0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,    // front bottom right, 1
   -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,    // front bottom left,  2
   -0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 0.4f, 0.8f, 0.2f,     // front top left,     3

    0.5f, 0.5f, -0.5f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,    // back top right,     4
    0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,   // back bottom right,  5
   -0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,   // back bottom left,   6
   -0.5f, 0.5f, -0.5f, 0.4f, 0.8f, 0.2f     // back top left,      7 
};
```

which does not compile.

Is there away to initialize a `unique_ptr` array as with a raw pointer array?

I have thought about using a `std::vector` and then "capturing" that with a `unique_ptr`, though I have not tried that yet.

Comment: `std::vector<float> vertices = { ... }` and you're done.

Comment: In the first code snippet, the type of `vertices` is "pointer to float". In the second, it should be "unique_ptr to float". As written, it's "unique_pointer to pointer to float".

Comment: If you are avoiding using a vector because you need a pointer note that `vertices.data()` or `&vertices[0]` will give you a pointer to the "array".

Comment: The initializer belongs to the float-array, so move the parentheses. Should work afterwards. Still, a vector is probably more appropriate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless very specific reason, you should aim to use `std::vector`. This is the standard type for dynamically allocated arrays. `my_vector.data()` returns a pointer to the data so it's compatible with C apis such as OpenGL.

```
// on the heap
std::vector<float> vertices = {
     0.5f,  0.5f, 0.5f,  1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,  // front top right,    0
     0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f,  0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,  // front bottom right, 1
    -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f,  0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,  // front bottom left,  2
    -0.5f,  0.5f, 0.5f,  0.4f, 0.8f, 0.2f,  // front top left,     3

     0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,  // back top right,     4
     0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,  // back bottom right,  5
    -0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,  // back bottom left,   6
    -0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f, 0.4f, 0.8f, 0.2f   // back top left,      7 
};
```

If you want vector (if you need resizing and such), simply use `std::vector<float>` as the type instead of `std::array<float, 48>`

---

Now if you want to fix your syntax but still use dynamic memory and pointers (I would advise against, even more because it's for OpenGL vertices and you know the size in advance) simply replace the type, construct it with the new array inside:

```
std::unique_ptr<float[]> vertices(new float[48] {
     0.5f,  0.5f, 0.5f,  1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,  // front top right,    0
     0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f,  0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,  // front bottom right, 1
    -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f,  0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,  // front bottom left,  2
    -0.5f,  0.5f, 0.5f,  0.4f, 0.8f, 0.2f,  // front top left,     3

     0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,  // back top right,     4
     0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,  // back bottom right,  5
    -0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,  // back bottom left,   6
    -0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f, 0.4f, 0.8f, 0.2f   // back top left,      7 
});
```

The `std::unique_ptr` type has a constructor that takes a pointer to the type `T`. The constructor is explicit only, so only direct initialization must be used.

Here's a [live example](https://godbolt.org/z/oTTKpk) with all constructor type.

Comment: Could you explain why a `std::array` instead of a native array?

Comment: @Deduplicator why a native array?

Comment: I want to be able to allocate the larger array structure on the heap.  Can that be done directly with `std::vector` or `std::array`?  If not, do I still have the option of using `std::vector` or `std::array` and then using, to pick one, `std::unique_ptr<std::vector>` to take advantage of heap memory?

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot Because you need not supply the size for one (DRY), and it does not use anything but the core language?

Comment: @user34299 vector allocate all data directly on the heap. It keeps the size and capacity, and data pointer in the stack.